# If $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers, then $\frac{a}{ab+1}+\frac{b}{bc+1}+\frac{c}{ca+1}\geq \frac{3}{2}$

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

> If $a$, $b$, and $c$ are positive real numbers such that $abc=1$, then prove that
> $$\frac{a}{ab+1}+\frac{b}{bc+1}+\frac{c}{ca+1}\geq \frac{3}{2}$$

#### Progress

I think the relevant concept would be  the application of AM/GM inequality.

Comment: I think the concept would be like the application of AM>=GM.

Comment: Some parentheses for denominators would improve the clarity of your problem.  An edit has been proposed.  If it is not correct, please advise so it can be rolled back or made right.

Comment: what should be the improvement. I didn't get it..

Comment: since the $a,b, \text{and}\ c$ are moving in a cyclic order couldn't you focus on one piece and use a cyclic summation (Don't know if that's the correct terminology.) $\sum_{a,b,c}$

Answer (score 5):

Writing $a=x/y$, $b=y/z$, and $c=z/x$, we simplify the LHS:
$$
\frac{xz}{xy+yz}+\frac{xy}{xz+yz}+\frac{yz}{xy+xz}=\frac{r}{s+t}+\frac{s}{r+t}+\frac{t}{s+r}
$$
where $r=xz$, $s=xy$, and $t=yz$. It remains to invoke [Nesbitt's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nesbitt%27s_inequality).

---

The linked wikipedia article contains a standard Cauchy-Schwarz proof:
$$
[(s+t)+(r+t)+(s+r)]\left[\frac{1}{s+t}+\frac{1}{r+t}+\frac{1}{s+r}\right]\geq9
$$
which after the simplification of the LHS implies
$$
\frac{r}{s+t}+\frac{s}{r+t}+\frac{t}{s+r}\geq\frac{3}{2}.
$$